# Install RSAT by GPO on Win 8.1

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy

I recently noticed that many Windows 8.1 Pro workstations do not have hidden shares, such as `admin$` enabled. I need to have such shares available for remote app deployment. I noticed that RSAT installation automatically enables administrative hidden shares on client computers that RSAT is installed. Hence my question, is there a way to deploy RSAT by GPO?
Since it comes as an update package I could use `wusa` and script installation but I do not want to break open door if there is a better option.

Comment: If the workstation does not have a need to have RSAT, then it violates the security principal of Least Privilege.

Comment: @davidw not really.  RSAT doesn't grant any rights; it provides a nice interface for users to use rights they already have.  Restrict using explicit controls.  Not to say this is a good reason to install RSAT though.

Comment: @Falcom Momot - thanks. This was merely a workaround. I can't afford to spend too much time on that project and it is >10 workstations so I was letting myself less-than-optimal approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think long and hard about deploying a software package merely for the purpose of enabling some shares.  Then keep thinking about it until it seems like a bad idea ;-)

Instead, maybe try just enabling the admin shares via GPO.  The specific values you are interested in are:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters
```

AutoShareServer and AutoShareWks are the values you need to add with a value of 1 (if not present)

Edit: Where this is located in the GPO editor escapes me at the moment - been a while since I dealt with domains and GPOs.

Comment: Agree that the OP's proposed solution is a bad way to resolve the issue.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks. I can script it in powershell or I'll just look for GPO template. If you recall the template, please post it. Thanks again.